# React ReduxForm img upload and validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create an img uploader inside my ReduxForm that will only accept imgs that are .png and no larger than 210x210 and 2mb. Also, the design says to swap the placeholder img with the uploaded file which I'm also struggling with. Here's my code:

```
renderProfileImgUpload(field) {
    const { meta: { touched, error }, label, name, accept, type } = field;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="login__fieldError">
                <small>{touched ? error : ''}</small>
            </div>
            <label htmlFor="img-upload">
                <img src="imgs/profile-select.png" className="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </label>
            <input type={type} name={name} accept={accept} id="img-upload" />
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    const { handleSubmit, showNextRegistration, showPreviousRegistration } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="widgetFull--white">
            <div className="align-middle row registration--fullHeight">
                <div className="columns small-3">
                    <img
                        src="imgs/account-arrow-left.png"
                        alt="menu"
                        className="img-responsive"
                        onClick={showPreviousRegistration}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="columns small-6">
                    <h2 className="registration__header">Edit account</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="columns small-3">
                    <h3 className="registration__index">2 of 2</h3>
                </div>

                <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this)) }>
                    <div className="columns small-3">
                        <Field label="Profile Image" type="file" name="image" accept="image/.png" component={this.renderProfileImgUpload} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="columns small-6">
                        <Field label="Username" type="screenname" name="screenname" component={this.renderUsernameField} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="columns small-6">
                        <Field label="First Name" type="firstName" name="firstName" component={this.renderFirstNameField} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="columns small-6">
                        <Field label="Last Name" type="lastName" name="lastName" component={this.renderLastNameField} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="columns small-12">
                        <button className="button expanded registration__btn" type="button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Currently I'm unsure whether it would be better to try and do the validation when uploading the img, or inside the handle submit function. Thanks for your help!